# How do I uninstall current minio and install specific version of Minio with kubectl?

Tags: kubectl, minio

I have installed minio using the following command.

```
kubectl krew install minio
```

Right now I have v4.5.6

How do I install v4.2.10 of minio kubernetes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krew doesn't allow to install any particular version according to docs yet.

So to uninstall run

```
kubectl krew uninstall minio
```

Then manually install the version you like with the below command.

```
wget https://github.com/minio/operator/releases/download/**v4.2.10**/kubectl-minio_**4.2.10**_linux_amd64 -O kubectl-minio
chmod +x kubectl-minio 
mv kubectl-minio /usr/local/bin/
```